# how to object value to its on property object?

Tags: javascript

how to object value to its on property  object ?

I tried like this

```
var obj = {
 a:2,
 b:this.a   
}
```

Then try `obj.b` it is giving `undefined` ..can I make function in object?

Expected output `2`

Comment: You can't do that. Also, obvious duplicate is obvious.

Comment: how to achieve this in different approach  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj = {
  a: 2,
  get b() {
    return this.a;
  }
};

console.log(obj.b);

const obj2 = {
  a: 2,
  b: function() {
    return this.a;
  }
};

console.log(obj2.b());
```

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/rqnbxw86/